# Make checkbox always visible in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Here is the new checkbox from bootstrap4 : [Bootstrap4 checkbox](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#checkboxes):

```
<label class="c-input c-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
    Click here
 </label>
```

The default `<input>` checkbox is hidden by default, it is visible only on click. Is there a way to make it always visible.

Fiddle : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alamzeeshan/mc9wow1t/2/)

Edit : This is how I want it to be by default.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on `the default checkbox is always hidden`?

Comment: I meant to say it is hidden by default. You can check the jsFiddle that I have added.

Comment: Perhaps change body background color to see it clearly.

Comment: do you want the checkbox `checked` by default? -

Comment: I want the checkbox unchecked by default with the blue border that come when you uncheck it manually.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense.

Comment: *the blue border that come when you uncheck it manually* - the blue border is selection, click on some empty space.

Comment: Now I found the issue why the checbox was not visible for me. As I am using a old monitor and the checkbox is of light gray color by default, so it was shown as white instead of light gray and was lost in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the style applied to the `.c-indicator` element when the checkbox itself is focused:

```css
.c-input>input:focus~.c-indicator {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 .075rem #fff,0 0 0 .2rem #0074d9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .075rem #fff,0 0 0 .2rem #0074d9;
}
```

If you want to have that apply at all times, simply reuse that style declaration in your own CSS, dropping the `.c-input>input:focus~` completely:

```css
.c-indicator {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 .075rem #fff,0 0 0 .2rem #0074d9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .075rem #fff,0 0 0 .2rem #0074d9;
}
```

[**Modified JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mc9wow1t/9/).